# Arrays.asList(an_array).contains(an_integer) always false.Why?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to build a lottery program and I want to check if a number already exists in the previous winning numbers (inside the array). So I was trying this

```
int[] winningNumbers = new int[6]; //array holding 6 random numbers

for(i = 0; i < winningNumbers.length; i++ ){

    int randomNums = new Random().nextInt(49) + 1;

    while (Arrays.asList(winningNumbers).contains(randomNums)){
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(winningNumbers).contains(randomNums));//always false 
    randomNums = new Random().nextInt(49) + 1;
    }
    winningNumbers[i] = randomNums ; 
    System.out.println(winningNumbers[i]);
}
```

Arrays.asList(winningNumbers).contains(randomNums) always was false regardless if the number exist or not so the while loop never was executed, so I solved it by writing a method

```
public static boolean findIfExist(int a[], int x){
   for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      if (a[i]==x){
          return true;
      }
   }
    return false;
}
```

My question is why  Arrays.asList(winningNumbers).contains(randomNums) always was false. What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `Arrays.asList` isn't going to work the way you expect for `int[]`.  You'd have to use an `Integer[]` or use an alternative.

Comment: I suggest use a set and then a while as set.size smaller than 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the interpretation of the varargs method `Arrays.asList`.  It interprets the type to be `int[]`, so that you receive back a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>`.  So none of the numbers you pass in will be equal to an `int[]`.

You could declare `winningNumbers` to be an array of `Integer`s, so that the array will interpreted as you expect, and you receive a `List<Integer>` back.  Your own `findIfExist` method works well also.